# How do I fully uninstalling Google Cloud Platform SDK?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Not long ago I installed both the Google AppEngine SDK and the Google Cloud Platform SDK. Recently I am experiencing development environment issues/conflicts with them both installed.

Looking to start over with clean installations, so asking for advice on the best way to fully uninstall Google Cloud Platform SDK from Mac (OSX 10.11.3)

Thanks.

Comment: Which OS are you running?

Comment: Mac OSX 10.11.  Thanks for asking, I'll update my original question as well.

Comment: I don't believe there's an uninstaller, however if you really want to remove everything then one approach might be to read the (very simple) installer script, work out where it put things, and then manually purge them. I know that's painful so I'd only propose it if you desperately need a solution.